# How does $\cos(\pi ) = -1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I know this is a very elementary question, but how does $\cos(\pi) = -1$? I thought the cosine function required a minimum of 2 numbers, the adjacent side and hypotenuse of a triangle?

Comment: The cosine function is a function of one variable, an angle.  But, in terms of a right triangle, that one angle can be defined in terms of 2 side lengths.  And, this is a lot simpler.  So, this is what you learn at a lower level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the angle is $0$ or $\pi$ we have a *degenerate* triangle, where the base and hypotenuse are in fact one and the same, except the hypotenuse has absolute length $1$ while the base, going *backwards* on the $x$-axis when $\theta=\pi$, has signed negative length, whence the $-1$.

Note that trigonometric functions can be described geometrically by ratios of signed lengths of triangle figures drawn on a circle, but these ratios are completely determined by the *angle* and so a trig function is purely a function of that angle.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Any point on the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$ can be parametrised by $\theta$ such that $0 \le \theta  \lt 2 \pi$, such that $$x=\cos \theta\\y=\sin \theta$$

Geometrically, $\theta$ is the angle made by the vector joining $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $(0,0)$  with the $x-$axis.

Can you cook these facts to see your result?

**Hint** You may want to use the picture below. (Courtesy: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Unit-circle_definitions))

$\hskip{2 in}$[image]

Comment: Seeing the unit circle helped put this into better perspective. I see now why my teacher prefers it over using triangles. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Glad to have been of some help here. :) @SubtleArray

Answer (score 5):

Cosine is a function where you put **one** number in (input) and you get **one** number out (output). The question is: how to I know how to find the number that comes out when I know what goes in. For cosine of a number (an angle) we can "draw" a triangle like below where the angle at $A$ is the input. Call the input $A$. Then we have that $\cos(A) = \frac{h}{b}$. So in a certain sense, the output is given by the two numbers (hypotenuse) and (adjacent), but we just have one angle - one input.

[image: image from Wikipedia]

([Image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trigonometry_triangle.svg))

Answer (score 5):

I like to think of it like this:

(pic from http://www.hitechnic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/SinCosGraph.png):

[image: (Sine and cosine)]

If you look in the picture above, it is clear that $\cos \theta$ is a positive number.  If $\pi/2 < \theta < 3\pi/2$ $\cos \theta$ is negative, because its length is in fact negative as the line representing $\cos$ is left of the y axis.

If you are familiar with radians, $\pi$ is $180$ degrees.  This means, if I were to draw the image above with $\theta=\pi$, the line would be horizontal, one point connected to the leftmost point on the circle, the other attached to the radius.  $\sin \theta$ is zero, as the height (y) has a length of zero.  $\cos \theta$ however is -1, because it has a length of negative 1.

This is sort of hard to explain without an animation or another drawing, but it is a simple concept once understood.